# searching excel using xlrd

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd

I am trying to teach myself how to use xlrd for a (conceptually) simple task:

I want to take a string through raw_input from the user and search an excel sheet for the string.

when found I want the program to print the cell row only

here is my non-working code to start with:

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('simple.xls')

sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

city = raw_input("> ")
for rowi in range(sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row(rowi)
    for coli, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell.value == city:
            loc = cell.row
            ??????????????
cell = sheet.cell(loc, 9)

print "The Ordinance Frequency is %r" % cell.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cycling through the columns in the same way that you cycle through rows

`for r in range(sheet.nrows):
            for c in range(sheet.ncols):
                cell = sheet.cell(r, c)
                if cell.value == city:
                   loc =  r //index of interesting row`

Comment: can you explain the following row: cell = self.worksheet.cell(r, c) ? doesn't the self belong only in classes? what objects in xlrd have the cell attribute?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error, in your case it should be cell = sheet.cell(r,c)

Comment: Please accept as correct answer, if the code worked for you, to help others.